# React Router useHistory navigate to routes programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make a wizard and I am having a little bit of problem with the buttons. I chose, for now to have next and back buttons for every single route, but I want to make a button component that knows how to navigate back and forward in the Router component. For now the buttons look like this:

```
<Button
    variant="outlined"
    color="secondary"
    component={Link}
    to="/signup/basicMet"
>
  Next
</Button>
```

Comment: Why don't you use history.goBack() and history.push(), where history = useHistory()

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `history.goBack()` and `history.goForward()`.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Button({
    variant,
    color,
    component,
    action,
    ...props
}) {

    const history = useHistory();

    function handleClick() {
        if(action === 'GOBACK') {
            history.goBack()
        } else {
            history.goForward()
        }
    }

    return (
        <button
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
        {props.children}
        </button>
    );
}
```

```
<Button
    variant="outlined"
    color="secondary"
    action="GOBACK"
>
  Next
</Button>
```